# Why do people throw coins in the river?

Tags: belief, practice

When I was travelling in train, I saw some people throwing coins in the river, so why do people throw them in the river? Is there any reason behind doing this?

Comment: Indians typically offer something at places which they consider holy. It is said that doing so brings them good luck by **gaining the grace of Lakshmi, the Goddess of Wealth**.

Comment: This is not unique to Hinduism. People all over the world of different faiths do it. It is a popular superstition all over the world, has nothing to do with Hinduism.

Comment: Well known scientific reason is  in ancient times Indian currency was made using copper. Water kept in copper containers is good for health.Storing water in copper and silver pots finds mention in ancient texts of Ayurveda for purification of water . ( http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312355/ )

Comment: Superstition, not a hindu practice IMO.

Comment: The original idea is to worship the river (with mangala dravyas) and seek pardon for causing her pain while crossing the river. Offering cash instead of actual dravya became a sort of substitute just as offering akshatas for the actual offering during puja. Along these lines, people may have started offering coin instead of turmeric, kumkuma, flowers etc. to rivers and this later became a rash act of flinging coins into the waters.

Answer (score 3):

> In ancient times rivers are main sources of water and it's being the
>   only sources of water for drinking and for irrigation purposes. Thus,
>   by **throwing copper coins in to rivers our forefathers ensured an
>   adequate intake of copper to the body via drinking water.**
>
> **Copper is a vital metal very useful to the human body and used to attracting dirt as it is mentioned in Ayurveda that it purifies
>   water**. Water was Stored in Copper pots which Kills Contaminating
>   Diarrhoeagenic Bacteria and, thus in temples also priests use copper
>   vessels to give thirtha/holy water.

Throwing coins in the river was one way our fore-fathers ensured we intake sufficient copper as part of the water as rivers were the only source of drinking water. So if coins remain in rivers for a longer time then it is beneficial for those who drink it.

Source: http://aumamen.com/practice/throwing-coins-into-a-river-importance-of-religious-practices

Comment: Yes, true. But I think this answer will be deleted because of scientific speculation But the problem lies in question itself which is not related to scriptures. IMO

Comment: @CR241 - Another thing is  in ancient times rivers do use to bring Gold , Copper ,Silver with their flow from mountains. (Gold Rush USA).  Coins usually in olden times  were made  from these metals which we gained from rivers.So its a kind of payback to rivers , who bring these metals.And returning  part metals to river , from which they used to get it.

Comment: It would be useful if some reliable sources are cited.